# Missing raspistill

Tags: raspbian, camera, raspicam, libcamera

`raspistill` seems to be missing in 5.10.63+ kernel (raspibian), the only option is to use `libcamera`. Since I need the `raspistill` environment, how can I manually install it?

Comment: raspistill is no longer supported on Raspberry Pi OS Bullseye https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/bullseye-camera-system/

Answer (score 1):

You can get it by installing the `libraspberrypi-bin` package.